# Cannot boot Ubuntu on dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. Upon startup, what I understand to be called the "grub menu" would display and I could choose Ubuntu or Windows. Today I was doing some work on Windows, and now I cannot switch back to Ubuntu. Both restart and shutting down/turning on go directly to Windows and do not show the grub menu. Even if I go to advanced boot options and select Ubuntu, it still boots Windows. My partition is in tact, as I can see all of my files via DiskInternals LinuxReader. I did not change any settings. As per other help sites, I tried disabling "fast startup" and "secure boot" but no change. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Boot-repair-disk fixed my problem
http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/